# Customizing CSS

Tags: css

How to locate the right url in css to have the backround images

my code here is

`background: url('/assets/images/banner/banner1.jpg/') no-repeat;`

and this is my local address

`H:\xampp\htdocs\web-repo\test\assets\images\banner\banner1.jpg`

Comment: How does the `<link href>` path for the CSS look like in `index.html`?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/assets/css/custom/custom.css">

Comment: Well, there is your problem, shouldn't it be `/test/css/custom/custom.css`?

Comment: what should it be the correct?

Comment: If your CSS is at `/test/assets/css/custom/custom.css`, your background is at `../../images/banner/banner1.jpg`

Comment: Also note, you have a backslash after the file extension in your posted background-image url path...if you have that in your original CSS, remove that

Comment: Thanks. Its already solve. Thank You!

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: The image file I saved is error banner.jpg.jpg 

And I used your method:
background: url('../../images/banner/header1.jpg') no-repeat;

Comment: Well, then you should accept [karthik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364851/2827823) answer, as they used the same logic, though based on another file structure, which you confirmed were correct...still, I updated that answer with the structure we now know is correct.

Answer (score 1):

With a file structure like this:

```
+--test
   +--assets(folder)
      +--css(folder)
         +--custom(folder)
            +--custom.css
      +--images(folder)
         +--banner(folder)
            +--banner1.jpg
   index.html
```

To set the background image from CSS

```
background: url('../../images/banner/banner1.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you index.html is in H:\xampp\htdocs\web-repo\test\index.html

```
background: url('/assets/images/banner/banner.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Your file is called banner.jpg and you are referring to banner1.jpg
also you should remove the `/` from the end.

To be sure your browser is refreshing the cache use `Ctrl + F5` to reload.

You can also try the "inspect element" tool in firefox or "inspect" in chrome by doing right click on your index.html. Try editing the css located in your right hand side until you get the right URL for the image. 404 means your URL is not correct.

Comment: still nothing to display..its still 404

Comment: Is your index.html in H:\xampp\htdocs\web-repo\test\index.html ? try Crtl + F5 to refresh cache.

Comment: also your file is banner.jpg and in your css you are using banner1.jpg

Comment: No. my file is banner1.jpg inside the folder of banner

Comment: That is not what you wrote "H:\xampp\htdocs\web-repo\test\assets\images\banner\banner.jpg"

Comment: Please mark this as your answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: @Joe When using absolute path (starts with a slash), it doesn't matter where the files are.